# SItecore 8.1 Image resize using hash in MediaRequestHandler

Tags: c#, image, resize, sitecore

I am having issue with the resize Image in sitecore 8.1. I gone through a lot of articles online but couldn't find what I am after, may be what I have in mind is not the right way but guess what I am still posting it here, In hope someone can guide me.

We have WebApi based project where we don't really have the layout it's all based on Json request and response. which looks something like this

Response

```
"components": [
        {
          "type": "background",
          "parallax": 0,
          "data": {
            "type": "image",
            "value": "-/media/images/pages/home/section-2.jpg"
          }
        },
```

This Json response is getting cached, so don't want to return the hashed image at this stage. So when the return image src is passed into image element at that time system will detect device type and pass that in query string something like this

**`"-/media/images/pages/home/section-2.jpg?type=mobile"`**

Based on the type define in query string. 
I am loading the resize image width and height value from sitecore item. All of this is happening is MediaRequestHandler class & DoProcessRequest method sample below

```
    public class MediaRequestHandler : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler
    {

    protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, MediaRequest request,
                Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media media)
            {
//Load sitecore item based on the type define in querystring

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["type"]))
                {

var mediaItemHashedUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(
                           Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(
                               media.MediaData.MediaItem,
                               new MediaUrlOptions()
                               {
                                   Language = Context.Language,
                                   Width = 100, // Width val would be coming from siteore item
                                   Height = 75 // Height val is also coming from siteore item
                               }));

                  }

              }
     return base.DoProcessRequest(context, request, media);
    }
```

Now question is how can I load this hashed image with out passing an additional request?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to not use the custom mediarequesthandler but instead customize the JSON response to also include the mobile image URL including the media hash? Then you can perhaps use that URL instead when the device is detected as mobile?

Comment: I am afraid I can't, this JSON response is getting cached, so don't want to return the hashed image url at all. We have quite a few different device types mobile is just one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the height and width in the request.options as below. I have not tried this myself. But, this should work.

```
public class MediaRequestHandler : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler
{
    protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequest request,
                Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media media)
    {    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["type"]))
        {
            request.Options.Height = 120;//desired height here
            request.Options.Width = 180;//desired width here
        }

        return base.DoProcessRequest(context, request, media);
    }
}
```